# SSRS 2012 Charts Not Rendering

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012

We recently upgraded to SQL Server 2012, and after a reboot a couple of nights ago, all of our charts have stopped working.

All charts in various reports are now showing as a broken image with a red 'x' in the top left corner when I try to view them from report viewer controls. This is happening in both the report manager and in a third-party application that uses the report viewer control to display reports.  Charts are also broken in report subscriptions that send the reports as an attached PDF.

However, the charts work fine from our custom web apps, which do not use the report viewer control--we have code to render the reports directly to pdf, and display them as a PDF in the web browser.

Does anyone know of any issues with recent updates that may be causing the issue?  Or, is there something that I should add to the web.config?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: As the charts uses .NET assembly you might have registration problems / or the report can't access the chart components. I had this on older version with dundas reports once. I had to re-register the components. Try run the reports inside the BI Studio with preview. You got get more infos there, then.

Comment: How do I re-register components?  The charts are perfectly visible from BI Studio preview.

Comment: I am not deep in the new 2012 config, so can't give you many more tips. Last time I had such troubles I saved my DB's and reinstalled SSRS. If you have third party charts, reinstall them. If you don't want you can turn on debug on server and call the page on server to get more detail infos.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem by running a repair operation from the SQL Server Installer.  I guess the Report Server was corrupted.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, this fixed my issue too.  I was beginning to lose hope