# Why aren't my charts in SSRS 2012 displaying?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2012, ssrs-2012

I recently moved several reports over to a new server. Everything works fine displaying tables and data, but charts are not displaying properly. It looks like the image is not rendering properly. My initial thought was that this was a permissions issue, specifically that the service account used to run SSRS needed permissions to a certain folder on the server that is used to generated chart images, but I can not find anything about this in searching for a solution.

This happens with old reports that display fine on the original server and new reports I try making on the new server.

EDIT: SSRS logs are showing a generic error in GDI+. Looks like this may be the issue, especially since this is running on a virtual server:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/37ed20b2-99bc-4e36-a14b-c9f8cc297be3/ssrs-2012-reports-with-charts-generic-error-in-gdi-?forum=sqlreportingservices

I am curious about a point made in this question:

> 2) Ensure write permissions on the "folder to which SSRS caches the charts"
>
> Well, firstly, I have not found a single article on the net as to
>   where this folder is; however, I tested this locally on the server
>   while logged in as Administrator with full privileges.  This doesn't
>   seem to apply to my situation either.

Does anyone know about this folder? I would imagine that running while logged in as an admin would not mean anything since the service account running SSRS would need the correct privileges.

[image: SSRS report with blank chart]

Answer (score 1):

Someone had a similar problem and the solution was to repair the SQL Server installation. I know it is quite long to run but it might be worth a try.

[Equivalent topic in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623002/ssrs-2012-charts-not-rendering)

Answer (score 1):

You can try restarting the report server. That worked in my case with Sharepoint and SQL Server 2012. Or repair the SQL server installation on the server as some posts suggest.

[SSRS 2012 Charts Not Rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12623002/ssrs-2012-charts-not-rendering)

Comment: Restarting Report Server worked in my case too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue when deploying a new report locally.

I restarted my Report Server service and the reports rendered fine.