# SSRS Chart not visible in report builder

Tags: reporting-services, charts, reportbuilder3.0

I created a simple report based on a dataset with three columns and eight records.  I tried to display this data on a line chart but when I run the report in report builder all I get is a grey box which looks like it may be the chart border (see screen shot below).  I've tried using different fields for the value, I've tried changing the aggregate function of the value, and I've tried changing the chart type but all I get is the grey box.

The fact that I don't even get a blank chart or some sort of error message makes me think that it's not a report design or configuration issue but that I'm missing some component, but I don't know what it would be.  The table below the grey box is from the same dataset so I know it's not a permissions issue and I know that I am getting data returned.

Has anyone ever seen this before?

[image]

I didn't save the report in the image above, I originally created it with the insert chart wizard.  Here is a new report, also created with the wizard, narrowed down to the time and value fields, it also shows only a grey box.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="DataSource1">
      <ConnectionProperties>
        <DataProvider>SQL</DataProvider>
        <ConnectString>Data Source=TestDBServer;Initial Catalog=TestDB</ConnectString>
        <Prompt>Specify a user name and password for data source DataSource1:</Prompt>
      </ConnectionProperties>
      <rd:SecurityType>DataBase</rd:SecurityType>
      <rd:DataSourceID>574876d0-bf5a-4165-8c60-ecca513284fc</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="DataSet1">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>DataSource1</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>SELECT
  AnaLog.[Time]
  ,AnaLog.[Value]
FROM
  AnaLog
WHERE
  AnaLog.Tag = N'well 6 gpm'
  AND AnaLog.[Time] &gt; N'10/01/2015 10:00:00'
  AND AnaLog.[Time] &lt; N'10/01/2015 12:00:00'</CommandText>
        <rd:DesignerState><QueryDefinition xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ReportingServices/QueryDefinition/Relational"><SelectedColumns><ColumnExpression ColumnOwner="AnaLog" ColumnName="Time" /><ColumnExpression ColumnOwner="AnaLog" ColumnName="Value" /></SelectedColumns><Filters><Filter Operator="="><ColumnExpression ColumnOwner="AnaLog" ColumnName="Tag" /><FilterValue>well 6 gpm</FilterValue></Filter><Filter Operator="&gt;"><ColumnExpression ColumnOwner="AnaLog" ColumnName="Time" /><FilterValue>10/01/2015 10:00:00</FilterValue></Filter><Filter Operator="&lt;"><ColumnExpression ColumnOwner="AnaLog" ColumnName="Time" /><FilterValue>10/01/2015 12:00:00</FilterValue></Filter></Filters></QueryDefinition></rd:DesignerState>
      </Query>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="Time">
          <DataField>Time</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="Value">
          <DataField>Value</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Single</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
  <ReportSections>
    <ReportSection>
      <Body>
        <ReportItems>
          <Chart Name="Chart1">
            <ChartCategoryHierarchy>
              <ChartMembers>
                <ChartMember>
                  <Group Name="Chart1_CategoryGroup">
                    <GroupExpressions>
                      <GroupExpression>=Fields!Time.Value</GroupExpression>
                    </GroupExpressions>
                  </Group>
                  <SortExpressions>
                    <SortExpression>
                      <Value>=Fields!Time.Value</Value>
                    </SortExpression>
                  </SortExpressions>
                  <Label>=Fields!Time.Value</Label>
                </ChartMember>
              </ChartMembers>
            </ChartCategoryHierarchy>
            <ChartSeriesHierarchy>
              <ChartMembers>
                <ChartMember>
                  <Label>Value</Label>
                </ChartMember>
              </ChartMembers>
            </ChartSeriesHierarchy>
            <ChartData>
              <ChartSeriesCollection>
                <ChartSeries Name="Value">
                  <ChartDataPoints>
                    <ChartDataPoint>
                      <ChartDataPointValues>
                        <Y>=Max(Fields!Value.Value)</Y>
                      </ChartDataPointValues>
                      <ChartDataLabel>
                        <Style />
                      </ChartDataLabel>
                      <ToolTip>#VALY</ToolTip>
                      <Style />
                      <ChartMarker>
                        <Style />
                      </ChartMarker>
                      <DataElementOutput>Output</DataElementOutput>
                    </ChartDataPoint>
                  </ChartDataPoints>
                  <Type>Line</Type>
                  <Style />
                  <ChartEmptyPoints>
                    <Style />
                    <ChartMarker>
                      <Style />
                    </ChartMarker>
                    <ChartDataLabel>
                      <Style />
                    </ChartDataLabel>
                  </ChartEmptyPoints>
                  <ValueAxisName>Primary</ValueAxisName>
                  <CategoryAxisName>Primary</CategoryAxisName>
                  <ChartSmartLabel>
                    <CalloutLineColor>Black</CalloutLineColor>
                    <MinMovingDistance>0pt</MinMovingDistance>
                  </ChartSmartLabel>
                </ChartSeries>
              </ChartSeriesCollection>
            </ChartData>
            <ChartAreas>
              <ChartArea Name="Default">
                <ChartCategoryAxes>
                  <ChartAxis Name="Primary">
                    <Style>
                      <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                    </Style>
                    <ChartAxisTitle>
                      <Caption>Axis Title</Caption>
                      <Style>
                        <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                      </Style>
                    </ChartAxisTitle>
                    <ChartMajorGridLines>
                      <Enabled>False</Enabled>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>Gainsboro</Color>
                        </Border>
                      </Style>
                    </ChartMajorGridLines>
                    <ChartMinorGridLines>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>Gainsboro</Color>
                          <Style>Dotted</Style>
                        </Border>
                      </Style>
                    </ChartMinorGridLines>
                    <ChartMinorTickMarks>
                      <Length>0.5</Length>
                    </ChartMinorTickMarks>
                    <CrossAt>NaN</CrossAt>
                    <Minimum>NaN</Minimum>
                    <Maximum>NaN</Maximum>
                    <ChartAxisScaleBreak>
                      <Style />
                    </ChartAxisScaleBreak>
                  </ChartAxis>
                  <ChartAxis Name="Secondary">
                    <Style>
                      <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                    </Style>
                    <ChartAxisTitle>
                      <Caption>Axis Title</Caption>
                      <Style>
                        <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                      </Style>
                    </ChartAxisTitle>
                    <ChartMajorGridLines>
                      <Enabled>False</Enabled>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>Gainsboro</Color>
                        </Border>
                      </Style>
                    </ChartMajorGridLines>
                    <ChartMinorGridLines>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>Gainsboro</Color>
                          <Style>Dotted</Style>
                        </Border>
                      </Style>
                    </ChartMinorGridLines>
                    <ChartMinorTickMarks>
                      <Length>0.5</Length>
                    </ChartMinorTickMarks>
                    <CrossAt>NaN</CrossAt>
                    <Location>Opposite</Location>
                    <Minimum>NaN</Minimum>
                    <Maximum>NaN</Maximum>
                    <ChartAxisScaleBreak>
                      <Style />
                    </ChartAxisScaleBreak>
                  </ChartAxis>
                </ChartCategoryAxes>
                <ChartValueAxes>
                  <ChartAxis Name="Primary">
                    <Style>
                      <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                    </Style>
                    <ChartAxisTitle>
                      <Caption>Axis Title</Caption>
                      <Style>
                        <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                      </Style>
                    </ChartAxisTitle>
                    <ChartMajorGridLines>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>Gainsboro</Color>
                        </Border>
                      </Style>
                    </ChartMajorGridLines>
                    <ChartMinorGridLines>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>Gainsboro</Color>
                          <Style>Dotted</Style>
                        </Border>
                      </Style>
                    </ChartMinorGridLines>
                    <ChartMinorTickMarks>
                      <Length>0.5</Length>
                    </ChartMinorTickMarks>
                    <CrossAt>NaN</CrossAt>
                    <Minimum>NaN</Minimum>
                    <Maximum>NaN</Maximum>
                    <ChartAxisScaleBreak>
                      <Style />
                    </ChartAxisScaleBreak>
                  </ChartAxis>
                  <ChartAxis Name="Secondary">
                    <Style>
                      <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                    </Style>
                    <ChartAxisTitle>
                      <Caption>Axis Title</Caption>
                      <Style>
                        <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                      </Style>
                    </ChartAxisTitle>
                    <ChartMajorGridLines>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>Gainsboro</Color>
                        </Border>
                      </Style>
                    </ChartMajorGridLines>
                    <ChartMinorGridLines>
                      <Style>
                        <Border>
                          <Color>Gainsboro</Color>
                          <Style>Dotted</Style>
                        </Border>
                      </Style>
                    </ChartMinorGridLines>
                    <ChartMinorTickMarks>
                      <Length>0.5</Length>
                    </ChartMinorTickMarks>
                    <CrossAt>NaN</CrossAt>
                    <Location>Opposite</Location>
                    <Minimum>NaN</Minimum>
                    <Maximum>NaN</Maximum>
                    <ChartAxisScaleBreak>
                      <Style />
                    </ChartAxisScaleBreak>
                  </ChartAxis>
                </ChartValueAxes>
                <Style>
                  <BackgroundGradientType>None</BackgroundGradientType>
                </Style>
              </ChartArea>
            </ChartAreas>
            <ChartLegends>
              <ChartLegend Name="Default">
                <Style>
                  <BackgroundGradientType>None</BackgroundGradientType>
                  <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                </Style>
                <ChartLegendTitle>
                  <Caption />
                  <Style>
                    <FontSize>8pt</FontSize>
                    <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                    <TextAlign>Center</TextAlign>
                  </Style>
                </ChartLegendTitle>
                <HeaderSeparatorColor>Black</HeaderSeparatorColor>
                <ColumnSeparatorColor>Black</ColumnSeparatorColor>
              </ChartLegend>
            </ChartLegends>
            <ChartTitles>
              <ChartTitle Name="Default">
                <Caption>Chart Title</Caption>
                <Style>
                  <BackgroundGradientType>None</BackgroundGradientType>
                  <FontWeight>Bold</FontWeight>
                  <TextAlign>General</TextAlign>
                  <VerticalAlign>Top</VerticalAlign>
                </Style>
              </ChartTitle>
            </ChartTitles>
            <Palette>BrightPastel</Palette>
            <ChartBorderSkin>
              <Style>
                <BackgroundColor>Gray</BackgroundColor>
                <BackgroundGradientType>None</BackgroundGradientType>
                <Color>White</Color>
              </Style>
            </ChartBorderSkin>
            <ChartNoDataMessage Name="NoDataMessage">
              <Caption>No Data Available</Caption>
              <Style>
                <BackgroundGradientType>None</BackgroundGradientType>
                <TextAlign>General</TextAlign>
                <VerticalAlign>Top</VerticalAlign>
              </Style>
            </ChartNoDataMessage>
            <DataSetName>DataSet1</DataSetName>
            <Top>0.4in</Top>
            <Height>2.10417in</Height>
            <Width>5.25in</Width>
            <Style>
              <Border>
                <Color>LightGrey</Color>
                <Style>Solid</Style>
              </Border>
              <BackgroundColor>White</BackgroundColor>
              <BackgroundGradientType>None</BackgroundGradientType>
            </Style>
          </Chart>
          <Textbox Name="ReportTitle">
            <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
            <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
            <Paragraphs>
              <Paragraph>
                <TextRuns>
                  <TextRun>
                    <Value />
                    <Style>
                      <FontFamily>Verdana</FontFamily>
                      <FontSize>20pt</FontSize>
                    </Style>
                  </TextRun>
                </TextRuns>
                <Style />
              </Paragraph>
            </Paragraphs>
            <rd:WatermarkTextbox>Title</rd:WatermarkTextbox>
            <rd:DefaultName>ReportTitle</rd:DefaultName>
            <Height>0.4in</Height>
            <Width>5.5in</Width>
            <ZIndex>1</ZIndex>
            <Style>
              <Border>
                <Style>None</Style>
              </Border>
              <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
              <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
              <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
              <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
            </Style>
          </Textbox>
        </ReportItems>
        <Height>2.53542in</Height>
        <Style>
          <Border>
            <Style>None</Style>
          </Border>
        </Style>
      </Body>
      <Width>10.04167in</Width>
      <Page>
        <PageFooter>
          <Height>0.45in</Height>
          <PrintOnFirstPage>true</PrintOnFirstPage>
          <PrintOnLastPage>true</PrintOnLastPage>
          <ReportItems>
            <Textbox Name="ExecutionTime">
              <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
              <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
              <Paragraphs>
                <Paragraph>
                  <TextRuns>
                    <TextRun>
                      <Value>=Globals!ExecutionTime</Value>
                      <Style />
                    </TextRun>
                  </TextRuns>
                  <Style>
                    <TextAlign>Right</TextAlign>
                  </Style>
                </Paragraph>
              </Paragraphs>
              <rd:DefaultName>ExecutionTime</rd:DefaultName>
              <Top>0.06944in</Top>
              <Left>4in</Left>
              <Height>0.25in</Height>
              <Width>2in</Width>
              <Style>
                <Border>
                  <Style>None</Style>
                </Border>
                <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
                <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
                <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
                <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
              </Style>
            </Textbox>
          </ReportItems>
          <Style>
            <Border>
              <Style>None</Style>
            </Border>
          </Style>
        </PageFooter>
        <LeftMargin>1in</LeftMargin>
        <RightMargin>1in</RightMargin>
        <TopMargin>1in</TopMargin>
        <BottomMargin>1in</BottomMargin>
        <Style />
      </Page>
    </ReportSection>
  </ReportSections>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Inch</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>e60b76a9-7915-42bc-bdb7-d6ddcbebbbb6</rd:ReportID>
</Report
```

>

Comment: attach the report design as well.

Comment: Yeah, what did you do in the designer?

Comment: added to the original post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else runs into this problem, I uninstalled report services and reinstalled, after that it worked fine

Comment: This is a very dramatic solution. Doesn't need that. Just restart Reporting Services and all work again. See more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21606592/why-arent-my-charts-in-ssrs-2012-displaying/22842018